# Entity Framework not respecting lazy evaluation

Tags: entity-framework

This works:

```
var user = db.Users.OrderByDescending(u => u.Id).FirstOrDefault(u => u.Email == "asd@gmail.com" && u.Password == "8a79hjhfas8d7fd89");
```

It correctly generates the sql statement that returns only one user.

The code below, which in theory is the same, brings all the users from the database and only applies the filter after that. It works as if I were doing a .ToList(), thus evaluating everything from the database, and applying the filter in a regular IEnumerable, instead of generating the correct sql statement:

```
public static User Get(Func<User, bool> predicate)
{
  return db.Users.OrderByDescending(u => u.Id).FirstOrDefault(predicate);
}

var user = User.Get(u => u.Email == "asd@gmail.com" && u.Password == "8a79hjhfas8d7fd89");
```

Is this a bug on Entity Framework or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

You are passing in a `Func<>`, which is a compiled delegate. Instead you should be passing in an `Expression<>` as the Get parameter, which is a syntax tree, which EF can analyze and generate query from instead of executing a delegate method against each result.

Answer (score 0):

EF doesnt know how to translate arbitrary Func delegates into SQL, so it has no choice but to load the whole dataset and then run the predicate on that result set.